# Schölkopf's One-class SVM: Role of $\rho$ in the cost function

Tags: svm

I have read and re-read the original paper and articles on Schölkopf's One-class SVM but elements of it still baffles me. The paper defines the cost function as:
$$
L = \frac{1}{2}||w^{2}|| + \frac{1}{\nu}\sum_{i}{(\xi_{i} - \rho)}
$$

> EDIT: The cost function above is **wrong**, the correct one reads:
>   $$
> L = \frac{1}{2}||w^{2}|| - \rho + \frac{1}{\nu}\sum_{i}{\xi_{i}}
> $$
>   The rest of the argument below follows the premise of the **wrong loss function**.

such that
$$
w^{T}\cdot\Phi(x_{i}) \geq \rho - \xi_{i}
$$
$$
\xi_{i} \geq 0.
$$

It seems to me there there is nothing in these equations that stop variable $\rho$ from increasing without bounds in trying to minimize $L$.

Here's my argument: rewriting the inequalities, we obtain:
$$
 \xi_{i} - \rho \geq -w^{T}\cdot\Phi(x_{i}) 
$$
$$
\xi_{i} - \rho \geq -\rho
$$
which are graphically represented below. The inequalities means that the offset slack $\xi_{i} - \rho$ lies above the blue line.

[image: Graphical representation of inequalities, the offset slack lies above the blue line.]

From this plot we can see that if a projected data point $w^{T}\cdot\Phi(x_{in})$ already lies inside the margin ($\leq \rho$), then increasing $\rho$ does nothing to change its offset slack $\xi_{in} - \rho$.

Conversely, if a point lies outside the margin, then increasing $\rho$ will have an effect of decreasing $\xi_{out} - \rho$.

Therefore, it seems like to minimize $L$, we are allowed to increase $\rho$ until $\rho = max(w^{T}\cdot\Phi(x_{i}))$ i.e. all the points lie on the 'wrong' side of the margin. Surely, this cannot be right. Am I missing anything in my logic?

Comment: If you rearrange the inqualities you have $\xi_i - \rho \geq -w^T \phi(x_i)$, note the minus sign on the right.

Comment: @MotiN you are right! The mistaken has been corrected.

Answer (score 1):

The short answer is: I have been fooled by parentheses. The correct reading of the loss function is

$$
L = \frac{1}{2}||w^{2}|| + (\frac{1}{\nu}\sum_{i}{\xi_{i})} - \rho.
$$

Therefore there is tension between increasing $\rho$ for the last term and the increase in the sum of slacks in the middle term as $\rho$ increases.

Comment: What if we dont want a clear label rather the distance from the plain (and the other sign)?  I am asking in the context of novelty detection https://activisiongamescience.github.io/2015/12/23/Unsupervised-Anomaly-Detection-SOD-vs-One-class-SVM/#sklearn-Users-Beware